# Newtonsoft Parse Json Error

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to fill my class with data from json. But I have a problem with getting list of codes for today and from forecast?

```
string js = @"{"query":{"count":1,"created":"2013-04-28T11:10:11Z","lang":"en-US","results":{"channel":{"item":{"title":"Conditions for Kazan', RS at 3:01 pm MSK","lat":"55.78","long":"49.18","link":"http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Kazan'__RS/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/RSXX0043_f.html","pubDate":"Sun, 28 Apr 2013 3:01 pm MSK","condition":{"code":"30","date":"Sun, 28 Apr 2013 3:01 pm MSK","temp":"54","text":"Partly Cloudy"},"description":"\n<img src=\"http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/30.gif\"/><br />\n<b>Current Conditions:</b><br />\nPartly Cloudy, 54 F<BR />\n<BR /><b>Forecast:</b><BR />\nSun - Light Rain Late. High: 57 Low: 44<br />\nMon - Rain. High: 59 Low: 36<br />\n<br />\n<a href=\"http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Kazan'__RS/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/RSXX0043_f.html\">Full Forecast at Yahoo! Weather</a><BR/><BR/>\n(provided by <a href=\"http://www.weather.com\" >The Weather Channel</a>)<br/>\n","forecast":[{"code":"11","date":"28 Apr 2013","day":"Sun","high":"57","low":"44","text":"Light Rain Late"},{"code":"12","date":"29 Apr 2013","day":"Mon","high":"59","low":"36","text":"Rain"}],"guid":{"isPermaLink":"false","content":"RSXX0043_2013_04_29_7_00_MSK"}}}}}}";
```

Comment: I don't think it visits the URL for you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this instead of above code

```
 public class Condition
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string temp { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class Forecast
{
    public string code { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string day { get; set; }
    public string high { get; set; }
    public string low { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class Guid
{
    public string isPermaLink { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string lat { get; set; }
    public string @long { get; set; }
    public string link { get; set; }
    public string pubDate { get; set; }
    public Condition condition { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public List<Forecast> forecast { get; set; }
    public Guid guid { get; set; }
}

public class Channel
{
  public Item item { get; set; }
}

public class Results
{
   public Channel channel { get; set; }
}

public class Query
{
  public int count { get; set; }
  public string created { get; set; }
  public string lang { get; set; }
  public Results results { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
   public Query query { get; set; }
}
```

using httpclient send the request

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);


string content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();


RootObject obj =   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(content);
```

Comment: i have used and will recommend to use [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/) for generating code

Answer (score 2):

[Parse](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm) method expects `JSON`, you give it an URL instead...

Download contents of URL

```
var json = (new WebClient()).DownloadString(url);
```

and then

```
JObject o = JObject.Parse(json);
```

**UPD**: it's not a good practice to completely change question after posting.
Originally you tried to parse `URL` as `JSON`, this answer shows how

**UPD2**: maybe JSON you posted now it's not valid,
e.g [JsonLint says](http://jsonlint.com/)

```
Parse error on line 9:
...           "title": "ConditionsforKazan'
-----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['
```

**UPD3** OK, it looks valid now.

Check out these samples on [querying using JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm)

Comment: sorry, it's mistake, case I was in a hurry

Comment: I'm checked : Json is Valid!

Comment: @nail, I've added link to querying with JSON.NET, check it out (especially last samples)

Answer (score 1):

pass a JSON string and then try to parse it. Only Json strings are acceptable by NewtonSoft. what u r passing is a querystring.

Use [JSON2CSHARP](http://json2csharp.com/)